# why my jar build by gradle is not visible in another terminal?

Tags: linux, gradle, build, jar, ls

i got the following problem :

in a terminal linux #1,
i do something like :

`

```
./gradlew clean 
./gradlew build
```

in a terminal linux #2,
if i list files like..

```
cd my-gradle/build/libs
ls -al
```

i can't see the jar which has been created.

but if i do..

```
cd my-gradle/build/libs
cd ..
cd libs
ls -al
```

then i can see the jar. what is that ? !!!!

what i want is of course, getting my jar listed in my terminal #2
when i build it in a termninal #1

any propositions ?

Comment: sounds like the jar is in ./build so why are you looking for it in ./build/libs?

Comment: The libs folder is deleted when you run `./gradlew clean`. So you need to `cd` there again to see the jar file.